# Showing function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for help with the following questions. I believe I have done 1) correct but need some guidance with 2)

1) Given,

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}x^n$$

show that it has the radius of convergence $R=\infty$

So using the ratio test,

$$lim_{n->\infty}| \frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}x^{n=1} \frac{n!}{2^nx^n}| = \frac{2|x|}{n+1}=2|x| (0)=0<1$$

Therefore the radius of convergence is $R=\infty$

2)But how do I show that the function,

$$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{2^n}{n!}x^n$$

is differentiable for every $x\in R$.

Deriving with respect to x gives me the following,

$$\frac{2^nnx^{n-1}}{n!}$$

Comment: recall the $e^x$ series at $x=0$ and note that $\frac{2^{n}}{n!}x^{n}=\frac{(2x)^{n}}{n!}$

Comment: I reckon you are new to power series? (In particular, you haven't shown -- yet -- that "every power series is infinitely differentiable within its radius of convergence")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{2^nnx^{n-1}}{n!}=\frac{2^nx^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=2\frac{(2x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$

Comment: do I then do the same as in 1) and use the ratio test?

Comment: Yes. It is essentially  the same series.

Comment: how did you manipulate the series to get that?

Comment: when I use the ratio test I get $\frac{n-1}{2x^{-1}}$

Comment: No. For the ratio test you have the limit of $\left| \frac{2(2x)^n}{n!}\cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{2(2x)^{n-1}}\right|$ that is $\left|\frac{2x}{n} \right|$

Comment: which is =0 therefore it is differentiable for every $x\in R$?

Comment: Yes. Do you see that this is the entire function $e^{2x}$?

Comment: yes I see that now, thanks for your help

Comment: last question, I believe I have calculated f'(x) correctly, does that look right to you?

Comment: Yes, correct! (The derivative of $e^{2x}$ is $2e^{2x}$).